# How to use wildcard in Cubevalue formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, powerpivot, powerbi

I am trying to get the values with wildcard in Cubevalue formula(below) in excel. I am not finding any solution.

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[Sum of Bookings_Net]","[Dashboard_Data].[Level_1].[Karnataka_India]")
```

I am trying to get the values where [level 1] ends with [_India], I don't want to create a calculated Column in Data Model as this condition may be used for different columns and different conditions.
I have also tried by giving cell reference(eg-[Cell A1] = "*_India*) as like below but I am not able to get the results.

```
CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[Sum of Bookings_Net]","[Dashboard_Data].[Level_1].["&A$1&"]")
```

kindly help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a `=CUBESET` function in cell A1.

```
=CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel","Filter([Dashboard_Data].[Level_1].[Level_1].Members, Right([Dashboard_Data].[Level_1].CurrentMember.Name, 6)=""_India"")")
```

Basically that is a language called MDX and the expression before "" double quote escaping is:

```
Filter([Dashboard_Data].[Level_1].[Level_1].Members, Right([Dashboard_Data].[Level_1].CurrentMember.Name, 6)="_India")
```

Then reference it in your `=CUBEVALUE` formula:

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[Sum of Bookings_Net]",$A$1)
```